# aframe disable device sensors pop up

Tags: aframe, webvr

I recenty made a website using aframe and glitch , when the website is on glitch everything works fine , but once I uploaded into my host everytime appears a pop up asking for device sensors permision 
"access this site over HTTPS to enter VR mode and grant access to the device sensors."

Do you know how can I stop this pop up to appear ?

Thanks

Comment: Does this message mean that HTTPS is required to read a controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serve your site over HTTPS. DeviceMotion and WebXR APIs are not available over HTTP

Answer (score 3):

You could also deactivate the device orientation permission modal by deactivating it with the following configuration:

```
<a-scene device-orientation-permission-ui="enabled: false"></a-scene>
```

Read more about it in the docs:
https://aframe.io/docs/1.1.0/components/device-orientation-permission-ui.html

Keep in mind, that you need aframe version 1.0.0 or newer.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your CSS:

```
.a-modal {
    display: none!important;
}
```